# In R, extract lists with same name from lists of list

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a list of lists where I would like to extract and combine those with the same name (in the example below I'd like to separate cof and pred). (I would prefer a tidyverse solution.)

Example data:

```
outputlist <- list(
    list(cof=0.12),
    list(pred=c(1, 2, 3)),
    list(cof=0.34),
    list(pred=c(4, 5, 6)),
    list(cof=0.56),
    list(pred=c(7, 8, 9))
  )
```

I would like to separate these so that I have one vector/dataframe with all cofs; and then another dataframe/vector with all predictions.
I've tried this (but it does not separate them):

```
 outputlist %>% bind_cols()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

outputlist %>% bind_rows() %>% split.default(names(.)) %>% map(na.omit)

#$cof
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#    cof
#  <dbl>
#1  0.12
#2  0.34
#3  0.56

#$pred
# A tibble: 9 x 1
#   pred
#  <dbl>
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
#4     4
#5     5
#6     6
#7     7
#8     8
#9     9
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a tidyverse solution, but a base R one-liner:

```r
lapply(split(outputlist, sapply(outputlist, names)), as.data.frame)
#> $cof
#>    cof cof.1 cof.2
#> 1 0.12  0.34  0.56
#> 
#> $pred
#>   pred pred.1 pred.2
#> 1    1      4      7
#> 2    2      5      8
#> 3    3      6      9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
outputlist %>%
      map_dfr(~ enframe(.x) %>%
                    unnest(c(value))) %>% 
      {split(.$value, .$name)}
```